# Adjusting table left and right in Elsevier's journal template

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, justification

I have been trying to adjust the caption and the table itself in the way the journal requested me but I have been failing for days. Below, you can see my code for table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[width=1\textwidth,cols=2,pos=h]
\caption{Parameter settings of MGA}
\noindent  
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{} }
\toprule
\textbf{parameter}              & \textbf{value}    \\\midrule
G                               & 5000              \\\midrule
population size                 & 100               \\\midrule
chromosome length               & 100               \\\midrule
$p_c$                           & 1.0               \\\midrule
$p_n$                           & 0.05              \\\midrule
tournament size                 & 4                 \\\midrule  
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:settings}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

However, the example given in the template is like this:

[image]

The class file I am using is `cas-dc.cls` [Link](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates)

Could you guys help me to make it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the file `cas-dc.cls`, [CTAN also contains the file `cas-dc-template.tex`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates) which in turn contains the following table related piece of code:

```
\begin{table}[<options>]
\caption{}\label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
\toprule
  &  \\ % Table header row
\midrule
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Adapting this to your table would lead to the following which should get you cloder to the expected output.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Parameter settings of MGA}\label{tab:settings}
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{}LL@{}}
\toprule
parameter                       & value             \\
\midrule
G                               & 5000              \\
population size                 & 100               \\
chromosome length               & 100               \\
$p_c$                           & 1.0               \\
$p_n$                           & 0.05              \\
tournament size                 & 4                 \\
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```